# bugzilla update error (3.6.1 to 3.6.2)

Tags: bugzilla

After patching to 3.6.2 using the .diff from bugzilla.org I receive 'Internal Server Error' when loading my bugzilla page - and Apache reports the following in error.log

Can't locate Bugzilla.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib/x86_64-linux-thread-multi lib /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8) at /data/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /data/bugzilla/index.cgi line 34.

Premature end of script headers: index.cgi

thanks for any help,
Bob

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have to run checksetup.pl after patching, who would have thought.

Bob